# Exporting HTML web server variables or data to a python code

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the orientation data from an html webpage on my web server on the raspberry pi sent over to my python script. I don't know if it is easiest to export this data to a table or leave it in the variable state? Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
   body {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

  .main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;  
}

.logo {
  width:275px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 300; perspective: 300;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
  <h2>Device Orientation</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Event Supported</td>
      <td id="doEvent"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tilt Left/Right [gamma]</td>
      <td id="doTiltLR"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tilt Front/Back [beta]</td>
      <td id="doTiltFB"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Direction [alpha]</td>
      <td id="doDirection"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container" style="-webkit-perspective: 300; perspective: 300;">
<img src="html5_logo.png" id="imgLogo" class="logo">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 init();
 var count = 0;

function init() {
  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    document.getElementById("doEvent").innerHTML = "DeviceOrientation";
    // Listen for the deviceorientation event and handle the raw data
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
      // gamma is the left-to-right tilt in degrees, where right is positive
      var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;

      // beta is the front-to-back tilt in degrees, where front is positive
      var tiltFB = eventData.beta;

      // alpha is the compass direction the device is facing in degrees
      var dir = eventData.alpha

      // call our orientation event handler
      deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir);
      }, false);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("doEvent").innerHTML = "Not supported on your device or browser.  Sorry."
  }
}

function deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir) {
  document.getElementById("doTiltLR").innerHTML = Math.round(tiltLR);
  document.getElementById("doTiltFB").innerHTML = Math.round(tiltFB);
  document.getElementById("doDirection").innerHTML = Math.round(dir);

  // Apply the transform to the image
  var logo = document.getElementById("imgLogo");
  logo.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
  logo.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg)";
  logo.style.transform = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
}


// Some other fun rotations to try...
//var rotation = "rotate3d(0,1,0, "+ (tiltLR*-1)+"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
//var rotation = "rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg) rotate3d(0,1,0, "+ (tiltLR*-1)+"deg) rotate3d(1,0,0, "+ (tiltFB*-1)+"deg)";
```

Comment: Do you need to send a request to a python script with some variables? Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Python CGI script that is configured to execute when requested, you can pass the data to it using GET or POST methods.

In you JavaScript add this:

```
var var1 = "something"; 
/*The variable you want to pass*/

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
  else
    {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      var yourVar =xmlhttp.responseText; 
      /*This is the response from Python*/
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","location/of/python/script.py?var1="+var1,true);
/*Change the above location to what you want*/
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Your python script linked in the JavaScript must start with a line like this

```
#!c:\Python27\python.exe
#!/usr/bin/env python
# one of these two depending on the platform you use
```

Then, import the cgi module and receive data from JavaScript

```
import cgi
# Any error in the code will make the server return HTTP 500 Server Error
# so for debugging, you can include the following module
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() # debugging

# Get passed data
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
var1 = form.getvalue("var1")
```

From now on, you can do anything with variable

```
# If you want, for example, want to return a reversed value of the input just print it
# However, you must have the following line
print "Content-Type: text/html\n" #Required
# Now, return what you want
print reversed(str(var1))
```

The printed value will be received by javascript in `yourVar` variable here:
`var yourVar =xmlhttp.responseText;`

From this point on, you can do anything needed with the returned variable via JavaScript

If you don't have Python scripts be executed when calling from browser, add this to the `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your Python script iff you are running Apache

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Comment: I tried the following code to my program HTML.py:                                                        import time

import os

import cgi

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

x = 0

while x == 0:
        var1 = form.getvalue("var1")

        print var1                                                                                                  This doesn't work it just prints None repeatedly

Comment: Did you run it from console or from the browser? If you are running it from the browser, it returns `None` because you are probably not passing anything. Try adding `?var1=Test` at the end of the URL

Comment: I added that but the program is still returning none. I am running the program from the console with the HTML server running from apache in a separate directory.

Comment: You must access it from the browser or send a request. Do you need to figure out the URL?

Comment: How do I do either one of those?

Comment: Comment the URL of your apache server and the location of your python script.

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you directly such as gmail hangouts or groupme?

Comment: Apache Server: http://192.168.15.76/orientation.html                                            Python script location: /dev/HTML.py                                                                  No I don't have either of those

Comment: You must first put the python file in a folder within your apache http so that you could access it from 192.168.15.76/somefolder/HTML.py. In addition, you must put a .htaccess file with content described above in the `somefolder` directory

Comment: So I should move the HTML.py to the /var/www/ directory with the index.html, etc.? And then I need to make the .htcaccess in the directory with the appropriate info?

Comment: Yes. You can also create a separate folder in /var/www/ directory and put both files there to keep things clean.

Comment: I moved everything to the same directory, /var/www/, then I added the info to the .htaccess script, I tried to run that but it still returned the None variable. I even tried adding the ?var1=Test to the end of the url but nothing happened.

Comment: Here is zip with two files .htaccess and HTML.py: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5N_FzMtVXjvcWtPZ3FwNkQ1SG8/view?usp=sharing. Put this in your apache folder and run it from browser. Tell me exactly what it returns.

Comment: If you are running on linux, make sure that the file is executable `$ sudo chmod +x HTML.py`